# Handler error when jsonEvent in eventstore server

Tags: javascript, json, database, eventstoredb

Error occured:

```
ReferenceError: jsonEvent is not defined
```

changing `jsonEvent({` to `JSON.stringify({` gives me :

```
  CommandError.js:357
        return new UnknownError(error);
```

changing it to a const `event = ({...}` provides no error, but no event data / blank.

when:

```
const event = jsonEvent({
  type: "TestEvent",
  data: {
    entityId: uuid(),
    importantData: "I wrote my first event!",
  },
});
```

Soruce details : ( following this tutorial)
https://developers.eventstore.com/clients/grpc/#creating-an-event

**Q**: What do i do to fix this error?

What am i doing wrong here, and how can i make that jsonEvent work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add import to be able to use this method.

```
import { jsonEvent } from '@eventstore/db-client';
```

Comment: I can add that the code in the documentation is imported directly from the `samples` directory of the client https://github.com/EventStore/EventStore-Client-NodeJS/blob/e2d3452ca9bfe985a7143fee4ee525aaa1a46a84/samples/appending-events.ts

Comment: Yup, plus if you're trying to play with EventStoreDB NodeJs samples, you can check my repository, where I have multiple samples showing how to start with EventSourcing: https://github.com/oskardudycz/EventSourcing.NodeJS